# Calculate distance between two points in an OpenStreetMap file

Tags: perl, openstreetmap, distance

I need to calculate the distance between two points in a map in the same way as Google Maps' distance matrix and get direction APIs.

Since I have to use offline more, I have to work with *OpenStreetMap* data.

I have downloaded the `planet.osm` file for the map data. How do I calculate the distance between two points with the *OpenStreetMap* file?

Comment: That depends, but if you want the orthodrome distance (and not e.g. a car route), and you have the coordinates, you don't need the map data at all, just use the formula: https://undergroundmathematics.org/trigonometry-compound-angles/the-great-circle-distance Also, if you don't need true programmatic access, just something which is not Google Maps and offline, you can use e.g. distance calculation in QGIS (with OSM or other data).

Answer (score 2):

There are already several [routing solutions for OpenStreetMap (OSM)](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routers), including various web services, standalone programs, and libraries. You are probably interested in one of the many [offline routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers).

Comment: The OP asked for the *distance*, not the *length of best route*.

Comment: He mentioned *direction APIs* which implies a route and not linear distance.